# What is the code : base()

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, constructor, default-constructor

What is the purpose of `base()` in the following code?

```
class mytextbox : TextBox
{
    public mytextbox() : base()
    {
        this.Text = "stack";
    }
}
```

---

Why At design time messages are displayed ؟

my code :

```
 class Class1:TextBox 
{
 public Class1()
 {
     this.Resize += new EventHandler(Class1_Resize);
 }
  void Class1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Resize");
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

`base()` in your code is a call to the parameterless constructor of the base-class of`myTextBox`, which happens to be`TextBox`. Note that this base constructor will execute *before* the execution of the body of the constructor in the derived class.

Every class's constructor must *eventually* call one of its base class's constructors, either directly or through chained constructors in the same class. Consequently, there is always an implicit / explicit `base(...)` or explicit `this(...)` call on *every* constructor declaration. If it is omitted, there an implicit call to `base()`, i.e. the parameterless constructor of the base class (this means that the call to`base()`in your example is redundant). Whether such a declaration compiles or not depends on whether there exists such an *accessible* constructor in the base class.

**EDIT**:
Two trivial points:

1. The root of the class-hierarchy does not have a base class, so this rule does not apply to `System.Object`'s only constructor.
2. The first sentence should read: "every non-`System.Object` class's constructor that *completes* successfully must *eventually* call one of its base class's constructors." Here is a 'turtles all the way down' example where the base class's contructor is never called: instantiating an object of such a class will obviously overflow the execution-stack.

---

```
// Contains implicit public parameterless constructor
public class Base { } 

// Does not contain a constructor with either an explicit or implicit call to base()
public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(int a)
        : this() { }

    public Derived()
        : this(42) { }

    static void Main()
    {
        new Derived(); //StackOverflowException
    }
}
```

Comment: So in my example is not required?

Comment: @mystack: No, it's redundant.

Answer (score 2):

No idea, it is unnecessary.  A constructor always calls the base class constructor automatically without you having to write it explicitly.  But that's what it means.  You'd have to write it if you don't want to call the parameterless constructor but one that takes an argument.